# Using DeveloperCredentials for AWS S3 Client in C++

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am writing a C++ application in Windows using the AWS C++ SDK and need help with Developer Authenticated Identities in order to upload/download files to/from S3 in my application.

We have a backend application using Cognito to get the temporary credentials for AWS (IdentityID & OpenIDToken). I know the ProviderName and the IdentityPoolID.
Rather than describe what I've attempted, I believe it's easier to show.
Below is the snippet.  I am trying to do the equivalent of "Refresh Identity" which is available in C# and Java SDK's.  C# and Java both use "RefreshIdentity" which defines an IdentityState(IdentityID, ProviderName, OpenIDToken, fromCacheFlag)

Based on some documentation I found, I created a new class (MyInheritedCognitoIdentityClient) derived from CognitoIdentityClient which overrides the GetId & GetOpenIdToken functions to return the IdentityID  and openIdToken received back from the server applicaton.  The GetID is called, but GetOpenIdToken is not called - as the documentation implies; instead there is a call to GetCredentialsForIdentity (which fails with NotAuthorizedException).
Below is my code snippet:

```
      `{
std::shared_ptr<MyInheritedPersistentCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = std::make_shared<MyInheritedPersistentCognitoIdentityProvider>();
identityProvider->setIdentityPool(myIdentityPoolID); // us-east-1:c373a2ca-b912-3839-a65c-8d4ce53d512e -> not real
identityProvider->setAccountId(myProviderName); // login.mycompany.net

std::shared_ptr<MyInheritedCognitoIdentityClient> cognitoIdentityClient = 
    std::make_shared<MyInheritedCognitoIdentityClient>(); // _cognitoID and _openIdToken 
std::shared_ptr<Aws::Auth::AWSCredentialsProvider> cognitoCachCredProvider =
    std::make_shared<Aws::Auth::CognitoCachingAuthenticatedCredentialsProvider>(identityProvider, cognitoIdentityClient);
Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(cognitoCachCredProvider);

/* attempt to upload/download here */
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `GetCredentialsForIdentity` server side, if not anyone can login in your own created provider (I'm assuming `login.mycompany.net` is custom provider)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Not sure I follow, though.  Our server side application (written in Java) calls GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest() (after validating the client's identity through our own mechanism) and returns the OidToken and the IdentityiD to the client.  I didn't intentionally call GetCredentialsForIdentity on the client; Something down the line called it from the S3Client constructor.

Comment: It is possible that I am using the wrong constructor for the S3Client; I went down this path due because it was the only thing I saw that utilized the OpenTokenID & IdentityId.

Comment: s3 c++ sdk docs says to use the way you are creating the s3client object...  your cognito_auth_role has access to s3 right?

Comment: When the line:  Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(cognitoCachCredProvider); is called, I see GetCredentialsForIdentity get the NotAuthorizedException.  After this, any subsequent call: s3Client.ListObjects() and s3client.PutObject() fails with the same error.    Is there any flag to set or anything to tell the client that i'm attempting to use a openIdToken, or a developerAuthenticatedIdentity?

Comment: And to answer your earlier question, I should definitely have acess to s3.  I have a C# application that is doing what I want to do in C++, but I just don't know how to use the openID token I get back from our server application.